# Obtener el precio de la fecha mas reciente

Tags: sql

Hola me estoy complicando un poco y espero poder obtener ayuda para hacer el resultado de la query que quiero para mi control de stock de entras y salidas:

en entradas tengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mis ventas tengo como salida
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT sq.sku, p.producto, sq.talla, SUM(sq.stock) AS stock FROM (
    SELECT sku, talla, SUM(cantidad) AS stock, sucursal, valor FROM entradas GROUP BY sku, talla, sucursal
    UNION ALL
    SELECT producto, talla, -SUM(cantidad) AS stock, sucursal, valor FROM ventas GROUP BY producto, talla, sucursal
) as sq INNER JOIN productos AS p ON (sq.sku = p.sku)
WHERE sq.sku = 2 AND sq.sucursal = 1
GROUP BY sq.sku, sq.talla, sq.sucursal
```

me genera:

```
SKU  | Talla  | Stock
2    | 34     | 12
2    | 35     | 2
```

Como puedo restar salidas a entradas y obtener el precio de la fecha agregada mas reciente
ejemplo:

```
SKU  | Talla  | Stock | Valor
2    | 34     | 12    | 25000
2    | 35     | 2     | 24000
```

Answer (score 0):

El primer problema sería: **cómo obtener el último precio de cada pructo/talla (según la fecha)**. Si únicamente tiene un precio por fecha/producto/talla, lo más simple es implementar esta consulta:

```
SELECT e1.sku, 
       e1.talla, 
       e1.Valor
       FROM entradas e1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT e2.sku, e2.talla, max(e2.Fecha) as Fecha
                          FROM entradas e2
                          GROUP BY e2.sku, e2.talla
           ) m
           ON m.sku = e1.sku
           AND m.talla = e1.talla
           AND m.Fecha = e1.Fecha
```

Dónde básicamente seleccionamos las filas de cada grupo dónde la fecha sea la máxima. Puedes agregar el filtro de tu consulta original para achicar el universo: `WHERE sq.sku = 2 AND sq.sucursal = 1`

Lo siguiente sería integrar esta consulta en lo que ya tienes, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT sq.sku, 
       p.producto, 
       sq.talla, 
       SUM(sq.stock) AS stock,
       PRECIO.Valor
       FROM (
          SELECT sku, talla, SUM(cantidad) AS stock, sucursal, valor FROM entradas GROUP BY sku, talla, sucursal
          UNION ALL
          SELECT producto, talla, -SUM(cantidad) AS stock, sucursal, valor FROM ventas GROUP BY producto, talla, sucursal
       ) as sq 
       INNER JOIN productos AS p ON (sq.sku = p.sku)
       LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT e1.sku, 
                 e1.talla, 
                 e1.Valor
                 FROM entradas e1
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT e2.sku, e2.talla, max(e2.Fecha) as Fecha
                              FROM entradas e2
                              GROUP BY e2.sku, e2.talla
                 ) m
                 ON m.sku = e1.sku
                 AND m.talla = e1.talla
                 AND m.Fecha = e1.Fecha
                 WHERE m.sku = 2 AND m.sucursal = 1
       ) PRECIO
       ON sq.sku = PRECIO.sku
       AND sq.talla = PRECIO.talla

     WHERE sq.sku = 2 
           AND sq.sucursal = 1
     GROUP BY sq.sku, sq.talla, sq.sucursal, PRECIO.Valor
```